# Javascript CORS "pre-flight"

Tags: javascript, cors, preflight

I'm so desperate because I can't see the light in this endless darkness, the problem is, that there is no way to stop "pre-flight" options response from appearing and of course can't reach certain API, I've been looking and reading stuff about CORS but without luck.

This is the function in the API that should display an array:

```
function main_get() {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: SOME-KEY');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header("Content-Length: 0");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    $array['results'] = array(
        array(
            "adId"=>"8847575",
            "make"=>"SOMEMAKE",
            "model"=>"Some model",
            "year"=>"2008",
            "version"=>"The version",
        )
    );
    $this->response($array, 200);
}
```

I'm using Codeigniter and REST plugin for the API.

Note that the headers are included

This is the code for the request sample:

```
    function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    function makeCorsRequest() {
        var url = 'http://*****/api/test';

        var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('SOME-KEY', 'dffs54f78v');
        if (!xhr) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 'CORS not supported';
            return;
        }

        xhr.onload = function () {
            var text = xhr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = text;
        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 'Woops, there was an error making the request.';
        };

        xhr.send();
    }

    makeCorsRequest();
```

Got this code from some CORS tutorial in the internet.

And still can't get rid of this:

> main.js:40 OPTIONS http://*****/api/test 404 (Not Found)
>   makeCorsRequest @ main.js:40 (anonymous) @ main.js:43 localhost/:1
>   Failed to load http://*****/api/test: Response for preflight has
>   invalid HTTP status code 404.

What am I doing wrong?

I know there may be an answer somewhere, but I've wasted 3 days at this thing and found nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution is not to remove the preflight, but the set up your server to respond correctly to it. I don't know CodeIgniter, but you'll likely need to make sure there's an endpoint defined for that URL and the OPTIONS verb... Right now it can't find it.

Comment: Sounds to me like `main_get` is called only for GET requests. Is there a `main_options` function where you could send the headers?

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan, but the server is already set up for this, or maybe that the headers are not the only thing I need to set up?

Comment: If you're talking about this line: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');` I believe that only sets it up so that CORS callers can use the OPTIONS verb; it doesn't set up the server to respond correctly to the verb.

Comment: many thanks @Bergi, looking for something related on what you mentioned, found a weird bug with the Codeigniter REST plugin, by just removing the 'options' value from this array: $allowed_http_methods.... and it worked, really weird though....